# MySQL: Not unique table/alias: 'product'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build SQL query to select image column, where product_id is coming from 2 different table.

Here is my database schema:

[image]

I want to select images of products from `ixml_prd_map.id_oc_prd`. I need to get from here to `product_image.image`.

On the picture you can see what I am trying to do, here is what I done so far, but it's not working. The error:

```
Not unique table/alias: 'product'


SELECT product_image.image FROM (product INNER JOIN ixml_prd_map ON product.sku = ixml_prd_map.id_oc_prd) INNER JOIN product ON product_image.product_id = product.product_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the join with `product_image`

```
SELECT 
product_image.image 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN ixml_prd_map ON product.sku = ixml_prd_map.id_oc_prd
INNER JOIN product_image ON product_image.product_id = product.product_id
```

Comment: Superb, thank you. One more qestion: How I can delete results? I tried to replace SELECT with DELETE, but I get error Unknown table in MULTI DELETE.

Comment: You need to use join while deleting for example for the above select if you want to delete from product table it will be as `delete p from product p join ixml_prd_map i on i.id_oc_prd = p.sku join product_image pi on pi.product_id = p.product_id` However if you create a question with what exactly to be done it would be easier to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You actually join the table `product` more than once.

In that case, you **must** give it an alias.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM       product product1
...
INNER JOIN product product2
...
```

Example by your provided code:

```
SELECT     product_image.image
FROM       product product1
INNER JOIN ixml_prd_map
ON         product1.sku = ixml_prd_map.id_oc_prd
INNER JOIN product product2
ON         product2.product_id = product_image.product_id
```